# Google Sheets code to send email with select cells once data is entered into a blank column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to create a Google Sheets script that once a value is entered into a column (Column M) that is empty, an email should be sent out (email address can be hard coded) containing the cell values for E3, F3, H3, I3, J3, K3, L3, M3, N3, O3 in the  email.

This script should run every time data is entered into Column M

```
function sendEmail() { 
        // return all data in active spreadsheet
        var values = 
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
        for (i in values.length) { 
           //iterate over each row
              var data= values[i][14];
              var emailAddress = "someGuy@gmail.com";
              var subject = "Marshal's Notice detected" 
              var message = values[i][E3] [F3] [H3] [I3] [J3] [K3] [L3] [M3] 
                  [N3] [O3];
            // if data cell is greater than one, send an email for this row
               if (data > 1) ;{
                    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
                   }
                 }
       }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Using `values[i][E3]` won't work - you need to pass integers to get to the values you're looking for in the array of data. I've made a few changes to your script and explained below.

```
function sendEmail() { 
  // return all data in active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    //iterate over each row
    var data = values[i][12];
    var emailAddress = "email@address.com";
    var subject = "Marshal's Notice detected" 
    var message = values[2][4] + values[2][5] + values[2][7]    //e3, f3 & h3
                + values[2][8] + values[2][9] + values[2][10]   //i3, j3 & k3
                + values[2][11] + values[2][12] + values[2][13] //l3, m3 & n3
                + values[2][14];                                //o3
    // if data cell is greater than one, send an email for this row
    if (data > 1 && values[i][15] == '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 16).setValue('email sent!');
    }
  }
}
```

I've changed your `for` loop to run for the length of values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
```

Then where you were trying to access E3 etc I've given the correct integers to access the specific cells you were looking for, for example `values[2][4]`, as they are 0 indexed, this will give you the cell on row 3 column 5 = E3.

To stop this script from sending multiples of the same email, I added a line that would set the value of column P to "Email Sent" then added a check in your `if` statement to make sure that it hasn't already been sent for that row.

```
if (data > 1 && values[i][15] == '') {
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  sheet.getRange(i+1, 16).setValue('Email Sent');
}
```

**EDIT AFTER ADDITIONAL COMMENTS:**

I've put together the following code which should match all of your new criteria.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  // return all data in active spreadsheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
    //iterate over each row
    var editCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var emailAddress = "email@address.com";
    var subject = "Marshal's Notice detected" 
    var message = values[i][4] + values[i][5] + values[i][7]    //e3, f3 & h3
                + values[i][8] + values[i][9] + values[i][10]   //i3, j3 & k3
                + values[i][11] + values[i][12] + values[i][13] //l3, m3 & n3
                + values[i][14];                                //o3
    // if data cell is greater than one, send an email for this row
    if (values[i][13] !== '' && editCol === 13 && values[i][15] === '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 16).setValue('email sent!');
    }
  }
}
```

1. The code now checks the column the data is being added into. To achieve this I've had to put it into an `onEdit` trigger, then used the event object to get the column the data has been entered into, then checked against this in my `if` statement.
2. Code was grabbing specifically row 3 for the data, this has now been changed to use `i`, which will grab the data for the row it's processing.
3. I've also added a check in the `if` statement to make sure that column N is populated, this should avoid any emails being sent if the data has not been calculated yet.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  The code you had supplied does in fact send the email.  But there are 3 other things I was hoping you could assist me with…
(1) The email gets sent no matter what column the data is entered into.  -> The intention is for any 
changes made to any cell in Column M will act as a trigger for the sendMail script

Comment: (2) When the email gets sent regardless of what row gets data inputted into it it always sends the same data in Row 1.  It is pulling the correct columns, just not the right rows.  For example, if a user enters a date into, ROW 232, COL M the data sent should be from Row 232 and [4], [5], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14]

Comment: (3) One of the COL (Column N’s) data is the result of  the =WORKDAY() function based on the data entered into COL M by the user.  Is there any way to delay the script itself from running until after the COL N has had time to update.  As it is coded now, the data is sent before the  WORKDAY() function has had time to manipulate the data in COL N

Comment: The code supplied answered the question you asked - none of this was specified in the question which is why it wasn't in my answer. In the future you should include everything you're looking for the script to do in your question. Saves the person answering having to re-write the code to match new requirements. Anyhow, I've added the new requirements to the code above.

Comment: When I run the code above  (the onEdit() function) I get the following error and script does not execute... TypeError: Cannot read property “range” from undefined  referring this line of code… 
var editCol = e.range.getColumn();
When I debug the code I receive this…
 ({onEdit:function onEdit(e) {var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {var editCol = e.range.getColumn();var...                      undefined

Comment: You won't be able to run it manually because it is using Event Objects `e`, it executes every time the script is edited.